# WPF Customise NavigationUI Control

Tags: wpf, templates, navigationwindow

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to customise the NavigationPanel UI Back and forward button, i basically just want to change the colors. I cannot find a property that can be set so i am a little stuck.

I believe the way forward is to amend an existing template and set the Page.Template property as the new control template? Am i going down the correct route? Where does this Xaml belong to, under the Application.Resources / Page.Resources?

I believe the Template is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970054.aspx

Apologies if this is a basic question but i am trying to learn Xaml / Wpf.

Thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example of this under samples on Msdn:

The link:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Customized-NavigationWindow-ced9d7af

I then used the default template as above and amended the xaml to the effect i wanted. Simple when you can find a sample. :-)